# Django - does transaction live after view ends

Tags: python, django, transactions

I'm using Django 1.10 -
Using middleware and doing some DB changes after view is called (see below). The question is - Assuming that some DB changes occurred on the Request (View called) - when getting to that part in the middleware, am I still in the same transaction or is it already done?

```
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    MyControlMiddleware.init(True)

    response = self.get_response(request)
    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.
    if response:
        # does the transaction still live here?
        # ..... code to run after request is done....
        MyControlMiddleware.clear()
```

Comment: How was the transaction created? By the [`ATOMIC_REQUESTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) settings? By the `transaction.atomic()` decorator on the view? Or something else?

Comment: We use ATOMIC_REQUESTS in settings.